# JS/jQuery/CSS dropdown suggestions box like Sublime's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently making a web app editor and I have already implemented the suggestions box. Right now, this suggestions box is fixed to the top of the page, but I would like to have a suggestions box that pops up underneath the text that I'm currently typing. Sublime's suggestions box is exactly what I'm looking for:

[image: example]

I've tried searching for tips on how to implement this kind of feature, but all I'm getting from my searches are for static fields (like search boxes that don't move) or drop down menus. I would like the suggestions box to pop up right under the current word I'm typing, meaning that it can't be fixed to a particular location.

Any tips on where to start with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a caret plugin that you can get the caret's position in. Then you could go `$(textarea).caret();`, then call the box's position a few pixels lower.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea, my thoughts so far (not tried in combination) are listed below. Sorry for not providing many links, but I think every part is small enough to look up on demand.

**Box itself**

It's possible to build such a suggestion box by an unorder list,`ul`. Just format it for a maximum size, and it's ready to use.

**Positioning**

You want to place it under the cursor, I guess you're using a `textarea`. From a quick search, there's a [plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position), which gives you the window coordinates of the text cursor. So we have a position now which can be used to position the box, great. Hint: It's a fixed positioning, just update it for each new character.

**Interaction**

So far we hopefully have a styled and positioned suggestion box. I would grab the `textarea` value and trim it down to the last word in front of the cursor. This string can bee looked up via AJAX, local or whatever you like to use.

Once you have a set of suggestions and filled the suggestions box, at least I would like to have keyboard support. To do this, just add keyboard listeners for up/down arrow, enter and tab key. For all four you also need to prevent the `textarea` to react by default on this keys.

A click listener on suggestion elements could be useful as well. After click or tab/enter you just want to modify the `textarea` value at the cursor position.